# An item that has patent, only this one kind of item exists, can I create a like item and patent?

Tags: device, walking

An item that is a health item for physical means for an individual. There is only one on the market for many years. Last updated patent was filed in 2013 and previous years. Can I take the idea itself and create my own that would serve the same purpose but not be exactly the same? As a like example, a prosthetic leg device for walking, simple design but there is only one company with a patent and manufacturing it. Can another be created and allowed a patent if it looks different but serves the same purpose? Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Could you please edit the title to not be all caps and to make more sense.

Comment: If you know the patent number, you should list it.

Comment: Patent #: US009408443

Comment: That patent should expire on 12-20-2031.

Comment: Okk thanks. So there isn't a way to create another without infringing on this patent.

Comment: I think my answer addresses that. If you can come up with a different approach or figure a way that doesn’t implement every step of the claims than you can avoid infringement.

Answer (score 0):

A patent's protection is defined by its claims. For you to infringe on a patent, you must implement every aspect of at least one claim. If you do so, then you can be sued by the patent owner. It is possible that the original patents on the product are now expired. You really need to do a patent search and determine what patents are relevant and when their priority dates are.

As for you second question, yes you may be able to obtain a patent for a device that serves the same purpose but works differently. Your idea would need to be patent eligible. Namely it would need to be novel, non-obvious and useful. These terms are specifically defined with respect to patents so you should perhaps read the [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patent) on Wikipedia. In any case, you would be well served to discuss your idea with a patent attorney or agent.